# 'Maven Dependencies' Folder is missing even though build is successful

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

'Maven Dependencies' Folder is missing even though maven build is successful in Eclipse.

I have 2 projects. In one project 'Maven Dependencies' Folder is visible under the Project parallel to src , target folder etc. Build is successful and all the imports in the classes of that project has no errors. No problem.

But in another project the 'Maven Dependencies' Folder is missing but build is successful. All the imports are showing errors in the left side and when I hover my mouse it shows like below:

Example:
The import javax.validation cannot be resolved
....
The import com.fasterxml cannot be resolved

When I click on the suggestion and do 'Fix project setup' and add the jar file manually it works.

But it should work when maven build is successful even though we are not adding the jars manually. Also the 'Maven Dependencies' Folder itself is missing which supposed to come under Project.

[image]

Comment: In the project with issues does your project build on plain command line?

Comment: It looks like you have edited the project properties manually (instead of two _JRE System Library_ items there should only be one). To sync and derive the project properties from the `pom.xml`, right-click the project and choose _Maven > Update Project..._

Comment: @khmarbaise yes the build works on plain command line as well. I checked.

Comment: @howlger yes I tried and it worked. Great. Thanks a lot. You can put the same thing in Answer section and I can accept the answer.

Comment: Great. Yasser has already given the answer (right-click project + Maven > Update Project...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have edited the project properties manually (there should only be one *JRE System Library* instead of two *JRE System Library* items).

To sync and derive the project properties from the `pom.xml` again, **right-click the project** and choose ***Maven > Update Project...***

Comment: Only the last proposal (right-click + _Maven > Update Project..._) makes sense here, since according to the screenshot it is already a Maven project (the project folder is decorated with a _M_).

Comment: I updated your answer based on the comments on the question (see above).